# Javascript simple multiply gives wrong result

Tags: javascript

I just want for example multiply **7.50*1.19**

Iam pretty sure it´s **8,925** but if i calculate it in my js i get **8.924999999999999** and i cannot get a correct rounding to finally get **8,93**

```
parseFloat(tarif.field_grundpreis * 1.19)
```

Result = 8.924999999999999

While **tarif.field_grundpreis** is **7.50**

It´s crazy, please help.

Comment: This is how IEEE floating point numbers work. This is the same in any language that uses floating point arithmetic.

Comment: More specifically, [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it with big.js and now it works perfect.